# Generate custom seqencial number using CTE in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a stationary where generating number are predefined with start and end range.

I have to use this stationary number for my booking. We use bulk insert data using XML. Inside this XML, I have my booking details. I want a query using CTE for generating sequential numbers for all of my bookings. If I send three booking identity numbers, this identity (primary key `id`) number should get three sequentially generated numbers. I tried using CTE but it is not working.

```
DECLARE @AccountWiseAMountDetails XML =
        '<AuditMammol>
             <Mammol POID="1807" />
             <Mammol POID="1808" />
             <Mammol POID="1809" />
         </AuditMammol>'

DECLARE @Jnal_nbr INT, @TotalCount INT, @POID INT

SELECT TOP 1 
    @Jnal_nbr = COALESCE(currrunning + 1, seriesstart) 
FROM
    branchstationary
WHERE
    stationaryid = 7 AND fyid = 3
    AND isover = CAST(0 AS BIT)
ORDER BY
    seriesend 

CREATE TABLE #tempLedgerList
(
     accountID INT, 
     Amount MONEY,
     BranchID INT,
     fyid INT,
     PODSubmissionID INT,
     Journal_nbr INT
)

INSERT INTO #tempLedgerList(accountID, Amount, BranchID, fyid, PODSubmissionID, Journal_nbr)
    SELECT 
        Y.ID.value('@AccountID', 'int') AS AccountID,
        Y.ID.value('@Amount', 'money') AS Amount,
        Y.ID.value('@BranchID', 'int') AS BranchID,
        Y.ID.value('@FYID', 'int') AS FYID,
        Y.ID.value('@PODSubmissionID', 'int') AS PODSubmissionID,
        @Jnal_nbr as Journal_nbr
    FROM 
        @AccountWiseAMountDetails.nodes('AuditMammol/Mammol') AS Y(ID)

SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(PODSubmissionID) 
FROM #tempLedgerList
GROUP BY PODSubmissionID

SELECT DISTCINT TOP 1 
    @PODSubmissionID = PODSubmissionID 
FROM
    #tempLedgerList
GROUP BY
    Journal_nbr, PODSubmissionID, fyid

;WITH GenerateGcnStationary AS 
(
    SELECT TOP 1  
        Journal_nbr, PODSubmissionID, 1 AS GCNCount 
    FROM
        #tempLedgerList
    GROUP BY
        Journal_nbr, PODSubmissionID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        GenerateGcnStationary.Journal_nbr + 1,
        #tempLedgerList.PODSubmissionID, 
        GCNCount + 1 
    FROM
        #tempLedgerList
    JOIN
        GenerateGcnStationary ON #tempLedgerList.PODSubmissionID <> @PODSubmissionID
    WHERE
        GCNCount < 3
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    GenerateGcnStationary.Journal_nbr,
    GenerateGcnStationary.PODSubmissionID,
    BranchID,
    #tempLedgerList.fyid, accountID, GCNCount  
FROM
    GenerateGcnStationary 
JOIN
    #tempLedgerList ON GenerateGcnStationary.PODSubmissionID = #tempLedgerList.PODSubmissionID
```

In the XML shown above, I have three ids. These three ids should get sequential numbers from "branchstationary"

Can anyone help with this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a sequence?

Here's a link to the CREATE SEQUENCE help documentation...

You can create a sequence to your specification and call the next number from it each time there is a need to do so.

Hope this helps...

[CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Then you can use

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR [SchemaName].[SequenceName];
```

to get your value